# Adding a new column to the dataframe in R that contains the most frequent value in each row

Tags: r

for example consider the following dataframe:

```
    X[[i]] X[[i]] X[[i]]
1      1      1      1
2      1      1      2
3      1      2      2
4      0      3      0
5      3      3      3
6      0      3      0
7      4      3      4
8      4      4      4
```

the result will be:

```
    X[[i]] X[[i]] X[[i]] output
1      1      1      0      1
2      1      1      2      1
3      1      2      2      2
4      0      3      0      0
5      3      3      3      3
6      0      3      0      0
7      4      3      4      4
8      4      4      4      4
```

The dataframe vary in their number of rows and columns in each execution. And the output column values are numeric

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Row 1 column 3, why did the value change from 1 to 0? or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the rows with `apply` and use `Mode`

```
cbind(df1, output = apply(df1, 1, FUN = Mode))
#  X[[i]] X[[i]] X[[i]] output
#1      1      1      1      1
#2      1      1      2      1
#3      1      2      2      2
#4      0      3      0      0
#5      3      3      3      3
#6      0      3      0      0
#7      4      3      4      4
#8      4      4      4      4
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`X[[i]]` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 4L), 
    `X[[i]]` = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), `X[[i]]` = c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're calculating is the [mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) of each row. The following will work for any number of rows and columns:

```
mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df$output = apply(df, 1, mode)
```

This will produce:

```
  V1 V2 V3 output
1  1  1  1      1
2  1  1  2      1
3  1  2  2      2
4  0  3  0      0
5  3  3  3      3
6  0  3  0      0
7  4  3  4      4
8  4  4  4      4
```